# dart generating all possible combinations list of lists

Tags: dart, combinations

I have a list of lists, similar to this:

```
a = [ [1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9,10]]
```

I'd like to create all possible combinations, like this:

```
[(1, 4, 7), (1, 4, 8), (1, 4, 9), (1, 4, 10), (1, 5, 7), (1, 5, 8), (1, 5, 9), (1, 5, 10), (1, 6, 7), (1, 6, 8), (1, 6, 9), (1, 6, 10), (2, 4, 7), (2, 4, 8), (2, 4, 9), (2, 4, 10), (2, 5, 7), (2, 5, 8), (2, 5, 9), (2, 5, 10), (2, 6, 7), (2, 6, 8), (2, 6, 9), (2, 6, 10), (3, 4, 7), (3, 4, 8), (3, 4, 9), (3, 4, 10), (3, 5, 7), (3, 5, 8), (3, 5, 9), (3, 5, 10), (3, 6, 7), (3, 6, 8), (3, 6, 9), (3, 6, 10)]
```

For python, there's a library that [does exactly this](https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/python/generating+all+possible+combinations+list+of+lists).
Is there a similar solution for Dart?
If not, I'd appreciate a simple code that accomplish that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could not find a package which does exactly what you want, but I guess your can do something like this if you want to introduce your own method:

```dart
void main() {
  print(combinations([
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6],
    [7, 8, 9, 10]
  ]));
  // ([1, 4, 7], [1, 4, 8], [1, 4, 9], [1, 4, 10], ..., [3, 6, 9], [3, 6, 10])
}

Iterable<List<T>> combinations<T>(
    List<List<T>> lists, [
      int index = 0,
      List<T>? prefix,
    ]) sync* {
  prefix ??= <T>[];

  if (lists.length == index) {
    yield prefix.toList();
  } else {
    for (final value in lists[index]) {
      yield* combinations(lists, index + 1, prefix..add(value));
      prefix.removeLast();
    }
  }
}
```

More efficient solution but also more risky to use since it does require the user of `combinations` to take care when consuming the output and make sure not to keep any instances of the inner `Iterable`:

```
void main() {
  print(combinations([
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6],
    [7, 8, 9, 10]
  ]).map((e) => e.toList()));
  // ([1, 4, 7], [1, 4, 8], [1, 4, 9], [1, 4, 10], ..., [3, 6, 9], [3, 6, 10])
}

Iterable<Iterable<T>> combinations<T>(
    List<List<T>> lists, [
      int index = 0,
      List<T>? prefix,
    ]) sync* {
  prefix ??= <T>[];

  if (lists.length == index) {
    yield prefix;
  } else {
    for (final value in lists[index]) {
      yield* combinations(lists, index + 1, prefix..add(value));
      prefix.removeLast();
    }
  }
}
```

The problem with this solution is the risk of misuse as the following example:

```
  final listOfCombinations = combinations([
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6],
    [7, 8, 9, 10]
  ]).toList();
  print(listOfCombinations);
  // [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]
```

Which should instead be:

```
  final listOfCombinations = combinations([
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6],
    [7, 8, 9, 10]
  ]).map((e) => e.toList()).toList();
  print(listOfCombinations);
  // [[1, 4, 7], [1, 4, 8], [1, 4, 9], [1, 4, 10], [1, 5, 7], [1, 5, 8], [1, 5, 9], [1, 5, 10], [1, 6, 7], [1, 6, 8], [1, 6, 9], [1, 6, 10], [2, 4, 7], [2, 4, 8], [2, 4, 9], [2, 4, 10], [2, 5, 7], [2, 5, 8], [2, 5, 9], [2, 5, 10], [2, 6, 7], [2, 6, 8], [2, 6, 9], [2, 6, 10], [3, 4, 7], [3, 4, 8], [3, 4, 9], [3, 4, 10], [3, 5, 7], [3, 5, 8], [3, 5, 9], [3, 5, 10], [3, 6, 7], [3, 6, 8], [3, 6, 9], [3, 6, 10]]
```

So, use the first suggested solution if you don't want the risk of this kind of issues. :)

Comment: Very inefficient to create sublists on every recursive call, though :)

Comment: @lrn I agree and the solution kinda sucks so I am going to remove it again... :) - Ok... the solution got accepted before I could delete it... I kinda feel obligate to make a better solution now so I can replace this answer... :D

Comment: @lrn Should be better now? I am a little surprised that if I do `Iterable<T> prefix = const Iterable.empty()` as parameter, it gets the type `Iterable<Never>` and it is not possible to do: `Iterable<T> prefix = const Iterable<T>.empty()`. This makes it kinda awkward when calling `followedBy` since `Never` is not a nice generic type here. So I guess the best I can do here is the workaround where `prefix` is nullable and initialize if `null`.

Comment: Since `T` is not constant (it depends on the invocation), it can't be used in a const expression. A const expression always evaluates to the precise same value every time it's evaluated.

Comment: Another approach is to use a list as "prefix", then do `prefix ??= <T>[]`, `yield prefix.toList();` and `prefix.add(value);yield* combinations(lists, index + 1, prefix);prefix.removeLast();`. That avoids the allocation overhead of `prefix.followedBy([value])` which is one extra list and one `Iterable.followedBy` (which will have its own iterator per nesting as well).

If documented as such, you could even `yield prefix;` directly, and just require the receiver to not modify the list or reuse it after calling `moveNext` again. More dangerous, but more efficient as well.

Comment: @lrn Yeah, but if we want to indicate we don't want modifications, we could properly change the returned value of `combinations` to `Iterable<Iterable<T>>` and yield the `prefix`. But as you say, that does makes it a requirement to consume the content and don't reuse it. I think it is safest here to just yield the `prefix.toList()` but implement your suggested improvement of using `removeLast()`.

Answer (score 3):

One approach could be:

```dart
Iterable<List<T>> allCombinations<T>(List<List<T>> sources) sync* {
  if (sources.isEmpty || sources.any((l) => l.isEmpty)) {
    yield [];
    return;
  }
  var indices = List<int>.filled(sources.length, 0);
  var next = 0;
  while (true) {
   yield [for (var i = 0; i < indices.length; i++) sources[i][indices[i]]];
   while (true) {
      var nextIndex = indices[next] + 1;
      if (nextIndex < sources[next].length) {
        indices[next] = nextIndex;
        break;
      }
      next += 1;
      if (next == sources.length) return;
    }
    indices.fillRange(0, next, 0);
    next = 0;
  }
}
```

This works by effectively treating the `indices` as a number in variable base based on the source list lengths, then incrementing it and creating the corresponding list.

Time complexity is still (Π<sub>i</sub>(`source[i].length`) * `source.length`).

Answer (score 0):

check out this answer. working for the problem you are searching for:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/57883482/11789758